# Print column A only if any of B, C, D, E & G contains Failed using Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

```
A               B                       C                  ............ till G

sucnpde067.advancemags.com-          Successful Full FS_UNIX_801_Fri_C Full_Backup 0B      Failed Full FS_UNIX_801_Fri_B Full_Backup 0B          ............ till G
sucnpde066.advancemags.com-          Successful Full FS_UNIX_801_Fri_C Full_Backup 0B      Successful Full FS_UNIX_801_Fri_C Full_Backup 0B  ............ till G
slnssde052.advancemags.com-           Failed Full FS_UNIX_801_Fri_B Full_Backup 0B              Successful Full FS_UNIX_801_Fri_C Full_Backup 0B   ........... till G
slnssde048.advancemags.com-           Failed Full FS_UNIX_801_Fri_B Full_Backup 0B              Failed Full FS_UNIX_801_Fri_B Full_Backup 0B          ............ till G
```

Print column A only if any of B, C, D, E & G contains Failed using Linux shell

Also I need, Print column A only if the final existing column doesn't contain successful.

Note -Coulmns are tab/comma seperated

Comment: So you want to use standard UNIX command line tools to print a subset of the input (anything before the first comma or tab), if the rest of the input contains the string "Failed", is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  Your question shows no effort to solve the problem on your own and looks as if you just want someone else to do the work for you, which is considered off-topic.

Comment: Simplify the problem into two tasks.. finding lines that contain "Failed" and getting the first column of a line.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the Unix / Linux shell and would be better suited on [unix.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the last column for which you don't want contain "successful" doesn't have any trailing whitespace...

```
grep "Failed" <FILENAME> | grep -vE "successful^" | awk -F'[\t,]' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Upvoted answer above containing `grep -v Failed` is wrong. It will find lines which don't contain "Failed". I would comment on the answer but I don't have high enough rep!

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v Failed <FILENAME> | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Also I need, Print column A only if the final existing column doesn't contain successful.

Answer (score 0):

`grep "Failed" FILENAME | cat FILENAME - | sort | uniq -d | egrep -o "^\w*"`

Comment: Also I need, Print column A only if the final existing column doesn't contain successful.